# Create a custom events in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net

I thought that as there's a `Form_Load` event, there will be a `Panel_Load` event also, but it turned out I was wrong. I'm pretty sure there's a way to create a custom event for the `Panel_Load`. I need help from you guys on how to create it.

Comment: 1. You can't do that unless you create a CustomPanel that inherits from Panel, but 2. What would you like to do there?

Comment: c# delegate event?

Comment: @TonyDong [i'm a beginner] idk about this delegate thing, maybe..idk, as there's a load event for Forms i want to know the code to apply the same event on Panels

Comment: How about put your panel control into user control, use user control load event instead of create your own event?